# "Товар" и "товарищ"

Tags: этимология

Меня интересует пара слов "товар" и "товарищ". Они однокоренные? И, если да, то почему они такие разные по смыслу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте во избежание недоразумений не говорить об однокоренных словах в историческом смысле, а называть их родственными на историческом уровне.
Эти слова действительно родственные, по наиболее распространённой версии оба восходят к алтайскому (монгольским в частности) tavar - имущество, скот (обычно - на продажу), отсюда и товар в современном понимании. Товарищ же первоначально означало, видимо, "партнер по сделке".

Comment: А суффикс "-ищ" продуктивен в данном смысле? Что-то не могу быстро придумать слова с такой же структурой.  
Или это был не суффикс, а какой-то древний корень?  
Может, этот суффикс родственен "-ище" (седалище, судилище ...)

Comment: Это очень древний суффикс, сейчас соверенно не продуктивен.  
Хотя - в порядке бреда - это может быть и древняя форма современного "-ист". Это ист пришло в русский из европейских относительно недавно, но должен же быть в славянском какой-то аналог, сам-то морф "-ист" очень древний, едва ли не индоевропейский. Посторюсь, это в порядке бреда. 

Совневаюсь, что он как-то связан с седалищем. Подозреваю, что в "седалище", "удилище" и проч. увеличитеный суффикс (страшилище, дядище) в несколько необычной роли.

Answer (score 2):

В "Историко-этимологическом словаре" П.Я. Черных сказано, что обычно это слово производят от др.-рус. **товаръ**, одним из значений которого и, м.б., старшим на вост.-слав. почве, было *стан, военный лагерь*. Таким образом, *товарищ* означало "из того же стана". В словаре рассмотрена также вероятная история изменения суффикса и связь со словом *товарище* (стан).

Аналогичной версии придерживается словарь А.К. Шапошникова.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку торговля требовала участия как минимум двух человек (*товарищей*), отсюда смысл этого слова: компаньон, единомышленник, что уже придавало этому слову определенную положительную в нравственном смысле характеристику, как надежного человека, на которого можно положиться. Слово *товарищ* получило в СССР и дружественных ему странах распространение в смысле уважительного обращения к человеку, изначально предполагающее доверие, взаимовыручку. Поиски других смыслов — это предвзятость и необъективность, вызванные издержками социалистического строя.

Думаю, что в данном случае наиболее вероятна версия с суффиксом -ище- не в смысле увеличительной формы однокоренного существительного, а в смысле обозначения места (существительное), где производится действие (глагол), обозначенное однокоренным словом, например: пасти - пастбище, стрелять - стрельбище, чистка - чистилище, хранить - хранилище, а также места (существительное), где распространен (или находится) этот однокоренной предмет(существительное): клад(захоронение) - кладбище; урок(уединенное место) - урочище, товар (предмет для продажи, обмена) - товарище( рынок, базар — место, где производится обмен или продажа товара, товарный склад). Отсюда товарищ — человек, связанный с этим местом или родом деятельности (синонимы: рыночник, базарник, торговец, торгаш, товарник).