# этимология слова товарищ

Tags: этимология

этимология  и происхождение слова товарищ

Comment: Повтор вопроса http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/45523/Происхождение-слова-товарищ

Comment: Был еще один подобный вопрос:  http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/3781/%d0%a2%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80-%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%89

Answer (score 0):

Большой этимологический словарь, 2013 г, составитель Климова М.В.

Товарищ ―  X—XI века, от общеславянского из тюркского, соединение tavar и is "друг", первоначальное значение "компаньон в торговле".

Answer (score 0):

В старорусском языке слово товар употреблялось, кроме основного своего значения, также в смысле имущество, состояние, с одной стороны, и транспорт, обоз, стан – с другой. Так, о князе Владимире повествуется в летописи, что он «приде в товары и посла бирючи (по есть послал вестников) по товарам».

В том же значении стан, становище существовало и слово товарище. Летопись сообщает например о попытке князя Изяслава спасти становища: «Изяслав же все, вседше на конь, гна до товарищь их, и види товарища горяща, и воротися опять».

В некоторых славянских языках товарин означает вьючное животное.
Следовательно, товарищ первоначально означает человека того же стана, соучастника похода или торгового путешествия, а затем спутника.

В старинных документах часто встречается выражение: «такой-то боярин со товарищи», т.е. с дружиной, набранной из жителей принадлежащих ему деревень, с подчиненными ему людьми, помощниками.

В этой линии развития слово товарищ вошло и в должностную терминологию. До самой революции существовали должности товарища прокурора, товарища министра, товарища председателя.